# How to replace the output timepoint with the ending point of a window in DolphinDB?

Tags: group-by, dolphindb

I used the clause `group by interval(pricetime, 5m, 'none', ,false)` for aggregate calculations in DolphinDB. The output table uses the starting point of each window as the pricetime. How could I modify the code to replace it with the ending point of each window?

Answer (score 0):

You can try DolphinDB function `temporalAdd` to add the window duration to the output pricetime. See the example:

```
t = table(13:01:00 13:02:00 13:03:00 13:04:00 13:04:59 13:05:00 13:07:00 13:09:00 13:09:59 13:10:00 as pricetime, rand(100, 10) as value)
res = select max(value) from t group by interval(pricetime, 5m, "none") as pricetime
update res set pricetime = temporalAdd(pricetime, 5m)
```